# Call script from custom npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I want to write my own npm package to analyse the structure of a vue project (vueanalyser). So I created a new package with `npm init --scope=@my-username` and set the `"main"` property to `index.js`.

```
// package.json of the custom package
{
  "name": "@my-username/vueanalyser",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
   },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "..."
   },
  "homepage": "...",
  "description": ""
}
```

I published the package and added it to my vue project (.node_modules/@my-username/vueanalyser). Now I want to add a command like `"analyse": "vueanalyser start"` to the script property of the `package.json` of the vue project. If I do so I obviously get an error, that the command is unknown.

So I realized, that I can call the index.js with `"analyse": "node node_modules/@my-username/vueanalyser/index.js`, but I have seen packages where scripts can be called with a much shorter way e.g. `"styleguide:build": "vue-styleguidist build"`. What do I have to change in order to call my script this way (`"analyse": "vueanalyser start"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [the npm `bin` property](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin)

This specifies executables to copy into node_modules/.bin.

1. Add the executable header to your index.js
   Add this to the first line: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
2. Make the file executable
   `chmod +x index.js`
3. Edit package.json
   Add the `bin` property:

```json
{
    ...
    "bin": { "vueanalyser": "index.js" }
```

4. Republish package
5. Install package
6. Find `node_modules/.bin/vueanalyser` is a symlink to `../<package_name>/index.js`!